# UITableView scrolling on reloaddata

Tags: swift, uitableview, horizontal-scrolling, contentoffset

I have UITableview in my project.
I am getting new data when clicking add new button on footer.
here is my app(demonstrated)
https://pastenow.ru/e327ad5e4978777b280552c4e92f032d

When clicking on Add New Btn
there is some little scrolling to up. i want to disable it and need to not scrolling uitableview to any direction.
here is screenshot (demonstrated)
https://pastenow.ru/e489ca3b9b5f78c31ad388cf8b3d02b9

i have checked setcontentoffset of uitableview, but it not works i dont know why.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for i in 0...10 {
            items.append(i)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func addNewBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        for i in 10...20 {
            items.append(i)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()    
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell") as! MyCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = "\(items[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: remove everything after append items into array and add only `tableView.reloadData()` line to refresh tblview

Comment: when i am write as you say, there is some little scrolling, i have found some solutions and wrote this code, but its not working too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also searched about this problem and until now I have not found a not *hardcoded* solution, but at least came to the following solution that works fine for my needs (it is almost the same as yours):

```
extension UITableView {

    func reloadDataWithoutAnimation(scrollingAt desiredIndexPath: IndexPath, at desiredScrollPosition: UITableView.ScrollPosition) {
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            reloadData()
            scrollToRow(at: desiredIndexPath, at: desiredScrollPosition, animated: false)
        }
    }

}
```

#### Usage:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: desiredRow, section: desiredSection)
tableView.reloadDataWithoutAnimation(scrollingAt: indexPath, at: desiredScrollPosition)
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

i have added this code, for working. i know its not real sollution, but works for now.

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: newsList.count - myPageSize, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: false  )
```